# How to remove the same item from Collection laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this collection:

```
Collection {#604 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => CarsMark {#596 ▶}
    1 => CarsMark {#594 ▶}
    2 => CarsMark {#594 ▶}
    3 => CarsMark {#595 ▶}
  ]
}
```

As you can see there is two the same items (594). How can i retrieve all items from with collection without the same items?

Comment: Are you looking to include only one instance of 594 in the final results or have both 594's removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the collection's [`unique`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-unique) method:

```php
$unique = $collection->unique();
```